# Using Laravel Echo without Vue.js

Tags: laravel-5.4, pusher, laravel-echo

I have an website built using Laravel 5.4 and I am building the broadcasting system with Laravel Echo and Pusher, but unfortunately the documentation lacks in specifying the steps needed to make it work without Vue.js.

Is there someone who had this configuration working? I'd need a complete step to step guide, since installing Echo correctly (I would prefer a CDN but couldn't find one).

Comment: Try to use socket.io instead of pusher.

Comment: The cdn link is here: <https://cdnjs.com/libraries/laravel-echo>. No need to install with npm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end, I figured out myself how to achieve Laravel Echo working with Pusher but without Vue.js

1. Follow all the instructions found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting).
2. Assuming you have Pusher installed and configured and Laravel Echo installed via npm, go to `your-project-folder/node_modules/laravel-echo/dist` and copy `echo.js` in your Laravel public folder (e.g. `your-project-folder/public/lib/js`). I use Grunt, so I automated this process, it's just for sake of simplicity.
3. Add the refer in your Blade template:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('lib/js/echo.js')}}"></script>`
4. At the beginning of your Blade Template, in the point marked below, insert this line of code (it's just to avoid a JS error using echo.js directly):

   ```
   <script>
       window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
           'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
       ]); ?>;
       var module = { }; /*   <-----THIS LINE */
   </script>
   ```
5. In your footer, after the inclusion of all the JS files, call Laravel Echo this way:

   ```
   <script>
       window.Echo = new Echo({
           broadcaster: 'pusher',
           key: '{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}',
           cluster: 'eu',
           encrypted: true,
           authEndpoint: '{{env("APP_URL")}}/broadcasting/auth'
       });
   </script>
   ```
6. If you want to listen for a channel, e.g. the notifications one, you can do it like this:

   ```
   <script>
       window.Echo.private('App.User.{{Auth::user()->id}}')
           .notification((notification) => {
               doSomeAmazingStuff();
       });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I am getting pusher and module is not defined error with this.

Comment: it is giving this error 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Answer (score 2):

I am using laravel websockets but I think it should be the same with the original Pusher.
So :

1. Install laravel-echo and pusher with npm
2. Go to ***your-project-folder/node_modules/laravel-echo/dist*** and copy ***echo.js*** to ***your-project-folder/public/js***
3. Go to ***your-project-folder/node_modules/pusher-js/dist*** and search for ***pusher.worker.js***, rename it to ***pusher.js*** and copy ***your-project-folder/public/js***
4. To the new ***pusher.js renamed*** add "export" before the "var Pusher" in the first line of code like so :

> export var Pusher =

Or you can just use this echo.js and pusher.js file from my repository  https://github.com/HarenaGit/laravel-websockets-without-vuejs

5. To where you want to listening for changes, you can listen like this

```html
  <script type="module">

        import Echo from '{{asset('js/echo.js')}}'

        import {Pusher} from '{{asset('js/pusher.js')}}'

        window.Pusher = Pusher

        window.Echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            key: 'server-notification-key',
            wsHost: window.location.hostname,
            wsPort: 6001,
            forceTLS: false,
            disableStats: true,
        });

        window.Echo.channel('your-channel')
        .listen('your-event-class', (e) => {
                console.log(e)
        })

        console.log("websokets in use")

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create event for broadcasting data as per the laravel document. And check console debug that your data being broadcasted or not. If your data is broadcasting than use javascript to listening data as given in pusher document.

Here you can check example : https://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start

Comment: Thank you @NisargBhavsar , but you are suggesting not to use Laravel Echo at all?

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem. But I have a two different domain for front-end and back-end. So I am trying to implement as I gave you answer.